# Props component on event VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to access a props of a component when this last triggers an event. This component is coming from http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/switch.

It has several props such as name, value and so on. I would like to be able to get the name or the value fo the switch when change is triggered.

Even more, how to access any props of the switch that triggered the change event ?

I tried this but I get undefined.

```
 <div v-for="organizer in organizers>
     <el-switch @change="changeOrganizers($event.target.name, $event.target.value)" :name="organizer.name">
    </el-switch>
</div>


var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        value1: true,
      }
    },
    methods : {
        changeSwitch(name) {
      console.log(name)
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hr6y79h/2/

Thank you

### Solution

```
<div v-for="organizer in organizers>
     <el-switch @change="changeOrganizers()" :name="organizer.name">
    </el-switch>
</div>


var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        value1: true,
      }
    },
    methods : {
        changeSwitch() {
      console.log(event.currentTarget.checked);
      console.log(event.currentTarget.name)
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div v-for="organizer in organizers>
     <el-switch @change="changeOrganizers()" :name="organizer.name">
    </el-switch>
</div>


var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        value1: true,
      }
    },
    methods : {
        changeSwitch() {
      console.log(event.currentTarget.checked);
      console.log(event.currentTarget.name)
      }
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
@change="changeSwitch"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hr6y79h/3/

That will give you the value.

The component will (probably) use

```
this.$emit('change', this.value)
```

which passes the name as the sole argument to your bound *"change"* event handler.

---

If you want the `name` as passed via props, I doubt it changes so just save a reference to it in your `Vue` instance / component, eg

```
data () {
  return {
    value1: true,
    name: 'test-name'
  }
}
```

and use

```
<el-switch ... :name="name"
```

Then you can always access it via `this.name`.

Comment: Thank you Phil it works well for the value, but since my switch is created dynamically I don't want to have to declare a variable for each of them to get the name. Is there any other possibility ? What is the general approach if I want to use any props of the switch that triggers the change ?

Comment: I edited the code so it is created dynamically. I,m sorry I forgot to precise that the first time.